# Vlookup to return multiple rows per customer

Tags: excel

I am working with Excel 2010 and have two worksheets.

Sheet1 contains a list of customer e-mail addressses along with a unique customer name.
D2 - Email addresses
C2 - Customer Name

Sheet2 contains a list of customers that are classed paying customers, it uses the same customer naming standard as sheet1.
A2 Customer Name

I need to link the two spreadsheets so can I identify which of the paying customers we have e-mail addresses for. I am not sure how to do this. In Sheet1 we have more than 1 email address per customer and I would like a central list of them all together even if we do not have an email address for the customer.

Thanks for the help

Comment: if you add screenshots of sheet1 and sheet2 would help

Comment: here you go http://oi62.tinypic.com/ap5s8.jpg

Comment: I see it... There are Three things you can do.. One write macro that iterate over row 1 and creates new string when Row A value changes.. Same thing you can do in formula (caution.. it would be a complex one) third there is add on kutools excel add on .. you can use it convert list into 2d data (like pivot for strings)..